# Amazon s3 upload file from our project Service [amazonImgBucket] target threw an unexpected exception (com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading an image to amazon s3 bucket from our  Java project. I am getting below error
We're sorry but it appears as if the information you have provided is incomplete.
Service [amazonImgBucket] target threw an unexpected exception (com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper)
amazonImgBuckeet is my service that we created.

Comment: why dont you post your code here, so someone might able to find the issue quickly

Comment: I resolved that but i am getting different error now Service [amazonImgBucket] target threw an unexpected exception (Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration)

Comment: //AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(OsafeAdminCatalogServices.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")));
        try {
            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            File file = new File(uploadFileName);
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                               bucketName, keyName, file));

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is related to a conflict between Spark's version of Jackson and the version that the AWS SDK needs.

You would probably be using the older version of aws-sdk for java or else Spark Streaming kinesis connector.

You just need to use the updated compatible versions of both.

There is an discussion available regarding this issue at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10256.

You can find more infformation reagrding this at https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/133